# how can I select the other departments from this query

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the following query

```
SELECT deptno, COUNT(deptno) number_of_jobs
            FROM emp
            WHERE job = 'SALESMAN'
            GROUP BY deptno
            ORDER BY number_of_jobs ASC;
```

What this does is to return me just department 30, while I want departments 10 and 20 aswell.

Like this

```
deptno  number_of_jobs
    10  (here it can be null or 0 doesn't really matter)
    20  (same like dept 10)
    30  4
```

I know this is fairly easy and I believe it's done using a join condition, but I just can't get my head around it.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` this with your department table. A `LEFT JOIN` returns all the rows from the left table, even if they don't have matches in the right table.

```
SELECT d.deptno, COUNT(e.deptno) number_of_jobs
FROM dept d
LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.deptno = d.deptno AND e.job = 'SALESMAN'
GROUP BY d.deptno
ORDER BY number_of_jobs ASC
```

Note that you have to use `COUNT(e.deptno)` rather than `COUNT(*)`, otherwise it will count the row with null values from the `emp` table. When you give a column name to `COUNT`, it only counts the non-null values of that column, so you'll get `0` for the rows with no match.

Comment: thanks! it was actually COUNT(e.deptno) number_of_jobs to return me 0, otherwise COUNT would have returned 1
Anyways thanks for the help!!

Comment: You're right, I frequently forget about that detail.